# run batch script after windows server restart

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-scripting

I am trying to run a script to startup some services after windows reboot.

I have tried one method: copying shortcuts of batch script in **shell:startup** folder. which eventually will start the scripts automatically but someone has to login to the system.

I am thinking about the possible ways to run the script after server restart without logon to the server.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Windows Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a Windows scheduled task and set it to run on system startup:

[image]